# Renaming multiple images with .rename and .endswith

Tags: python, rename, batch-rename

I've been trying to get this to work, but I feel like I'm missing something.  There is a large collection of images in a folder that I need to rename just part of the filename.  For example, I'm trying to rename the "RJ_200", "RJ_600", and "RJ_60"1 all to the same "RJ_500", while keeping the rest of the filename intact.

```
Image01.Food.RJ_200.jpg
Image02.Food.RJ_200.jpg
Image03.Basket.RJ_600.jpg
Image04.Basket.RJ_600.jpg
Image05.Cup.RJ_601.jpg
Image06.Cup.RJ_602.jpg
```

This is what I have so far, but it keeps just giving me the "else" instead of actually renaming any of them:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import sys

user_profile = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
dir = user_profile + "\Desktop" + "\Working"

print (os.listdir(dir))

for images in dir:
    if images.endswith("RJ_***.jpg"):
        os.rename("RJ_***.jpg", "RJ_500.jpg")
    else:
        print ("Arg!")
```

Comment: *** doesn't work in this case. But I don't know what to write instead of those

Comment: Literal backslashes in strings need to be doubled, or have an `r` raw string prefix added. i.e. `user_profile + "\\Desktop\\Working"` or `user_profile + r"\Desktop\Working"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python string method `endswith` does not do pattern-matching with `*`, so you're looking for filenames which explicitly include the asterisk character and not finding any.
Try using regular expressions to match your filenames and then building your target filename explicitly:

```
import os
import re
patt = r'RJ_\d\d\d'

user_profile = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
path = os.path.join(user_profile, "Desktop", "Working")
image_files = os.listdir(path)

for filename in image_files:
    flds = filename.split('.')
    try:
        frag = flds[2]
    except IndexError:
        continue
    if re.match(patt, flds[2]):
        from_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
        to_name = '.'.join([flds[0], flds[1], 'RJ_500', 'jpg'])
        os.rename(from_name, os.path.join(path, to_name))
```

Note that you need to do your matching with the file's basename and join on the rest of the path later.

Comment: I tried it, but it keeps giving me an error at the "re.match(patt, flds[2]):

It says "list index out of range"

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to learn.  I'm guessing it's because I need to create a counter for it?  Otherwise it just keeps iterating over and over again in the same folder?

Comment: Evidently some of the files in your directory are not of the form you want to change: you can skip these ones using the code in the edit I've made.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!  It worked like I wanted and sent me down a much more complicated path.  Which is  good, I think.  lol

Comment: Literal backslashes in strings need to be doubled, or have an `r` raw string prefix added. So in addition doing that for the `path` variable, in your answer it would need to be done to the literal assigned to `patt`.

Comment: That's a fair comment (although I don't think \d, \W and \D actually correspond to valid escape sequences do they?) -- I've used `os.path.join` as I should have and a raw string for the regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.endswith`. You can split the image file name up using `.split` and check the results. Since there are several suffix strings involved, I've put them all into a `set` for fast membership testing.

```
import os
import re
import sys

suffixes = {"RJ_200", "RJ_600", "RJ_601"}
new_suffix = "RJ_500"

user_profile = os.environ["USERPROFILE"]
dir = os.path.join(user_profile, "Desktop", "Working")

for image_name in os.listdir(dir):
    pieces = image_name.split(".")
    if pieces[2] in suffixes:
        from_path = os.path.join(dir, image_name)
        new_name = ".".join([pieces[0], pieces[1], new_suffix, pieces[3]])
        to_path = os.path.join(dir, new_name)
        print("renaming {} to {}".format(from_path, to_path))
        os.rename(from_path, to_path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your take on it!  It gave me some more things to look into.

Comment: Glad to hear that. How about at least an upvote, even if you accept the other answer?

Comment: Require more reputation!  I will do it once that happens.